# How can I search in Visual Studio and get it to ignore what is commented out?

Tags: visual-studio, search

I am refactoring a C++ codebase in Visual Studio 2005.  I'm about half way through this process now and I've commented out a lot of old code and replaced or moved it.  Now I'm searching to see that I have to change next but the search function keeps bringing me the old commented out stuff I no longer care about. I don't really want to delete that old code yet, just in case.

Is there any way I can search all files in the solution and get results ignoring what is commented out?  I don't see a way in visual studio itself, is the perhaps a plug-in that would do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exclude comments when searching in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314366/exclude-comments-when-searching-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score -17, accepted):

delete the commented out code, it is in source control right? there is no need to keep it in the file as well.

Comment: Finally this turned out to be in the only workable solution.  The code was in CVS which I guess is better than nothing. I still think this type of search is something that it would be very useful for visual studio to provide out of the box.  The code colouring seems to have no problem working out what is a comment and what is not so it should be relatively easy for them to provide a search which excludes comments.

Comment: The trouble I have found is that it is not always commented out code that you want to exclude. Legitimate comments often refer to function and type names and it would be handy to exclude those comments as well. This is particularly an issue when you have documentation comments like C# does.

Answer (score 52):

As the other provided solutions didn't work for me, I finally discovered the following solution:

`^~(:b*//).*your_search_term`

Short explanation:

- `^` from beginning of line
- `~(` NOT the following
- `:b*` any number of white spaces, followed by
- `//` the comment start
- `)` end of NOT
- `.*` any character may appear before
- `your_search_term` your search term :-)

Obviouly this will only work for `//` and `///`-style comments.

You must click "Use Regular Expressions " Button (dot and asterisk) on your find window to apply regex search

In newer versions of visual studio .net regex is used which has a slightly different syntax:

```
^(?![ \t]*//).*your_search_term
```

Comment: fyi, just remove the ~  if you want to ONLY search comments

Comment: In newer versions of VS tilde won't work, use the following:       ^(?![ \t]*//).*your_search_term

Answer (score 3):

My take:

yes you can use regular expressions, those tend to be too slow and thinking about them distracts from focusing on real stuff - your software.

I prefer non-obtrusive semi-inteligent methods:

Poor man's method:
Find references if you happen to use intelisense on

Or even better:
Visual assist and it's colored "Find all References" and "Go To" mapped to handy shortcuts. This speeds up navigation tremendously.

Comment: And how does that work if you are looking for "delete"?

Answer (score 2):

If you comment your old code with `//` you can use regular expressions while searching for something in your codebase. Something like this for example: `^[^/][^/].*your_function_name.*`.

Answer (score 2):

Previous answer gave a false-positive on cases where otherwise matching lines were placed on lines containing other source:

```
++i; // your_search_term gets found, don't want it found
```

So replaced the `:b*` with `.*` and added the `<>` so only entire words are found, and then went after some of the older C-style comments where there's a `/*` on the line:

```
^~(.*//)~(.*/\*).*<your_search_term>
```

In my case I was hunting for all instances of `new`, not amenable to refactor assistance, and boatloads of false-positives.  I also haven't figured out how to avoid matches in quoted strings.

Comment: Note: Stack Overflow often rearanges answers so what is the "Previous answer" now may no be in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add on, as I was doing a "find all" for division operator used in the code, used the below to exclude comments as well as `</` and `/>` from aspx files:

```
^~(.*//)~(.*/\*)~(.*\<\/)~(.*/\>).*/
```

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Basic within Visual Studio 2015, I was able to search for text outside of comments by adapting glassiko's comment from the most upvoted answer

```
^(?![ \t]*[']).*mysearchterm
```

And in C# you would use glassiko's comment exactly as it was

```
 ^(?![ \t]*//).*mysearchterm
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use **\s** I think. `^(?![\s]*//).*your_search_term`