# Exclude comments when searching in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to perform searches (Find / Find in Files) in visual studio that will exclude matches in comments?  While sometimes it is useful, other times it is the opposite.  For all of the options presented, I figured it would be in there, but I can't find it if it is.

I am using VS 2010/2012 about equally by the way.

Comment: related: [Feature request: 'Ignore comments' checkbox in the 'Find' dialog] https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/11688 ; still not solved

Comment: Hi! You actually never accepted an answer in all the years, so maybe you wanna check in and see if over ten years later your question could finally be answered ;-)

Answer (score 57):

Here's the regex that works for me for newer versions of Visual Studio:

```
^(?![ \t]*//).*your_search_term
```

Note that the syntax changed as of VS 2012:

> Visual Studio 2012 uses .NET Framework regular expressions to find and
>   replace text. In Visual Studio 2010 and earlier versions, Visual
>   Studio used custom regular expression syntax in the Find and Replace
>   windows.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2k3te2cs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: There was a space in front of the expression. Took me a while to figure out why it wasn't working for me. Thanks.

Comment: It still matches lines starting with `*` as for instance jsdoc comments do.

Answer (score 26):

you could try the regex as below:

```
^~(:b*//).*your_search_term
```

Short explanation:

- `^` from beginning of line
- `~(` NOT the following
- `:b*` any number of white spaces, followed by
- `//` the comment start
- `)` end of NOT
- `.*` any character may appear before
- `your_search_term` your search term :-)

[saw this at another post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153876/how-can-i-search-in-visual-studio-and-get-it-to-ignore-what-is-commented-out)

Comment: Very cool.  I don't think that it will handle block comments (/* ... */) but I really like how the regex is broken down.

Comment: Broken for me!  According to docs the syntax changed: ^(?![ \t]*//).*your_search_term.  Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(vs.netregularexpressionhelp);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5)&rd=true

Comment: @JaredThirsk I suggest you to add an answer ;).

Comment: @JaredThirsk broken link

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean ***any*** comments, ***both*** *single-* (`//`) ***and*** **MULTI-LINE** (`/**/`).

The other answers only deal with single-line-comments. So here comes my VS Code-compatible **Regex *for both*** of them at the same time:

```
(?<!//.*)(?!(/\*).*)YOUR_SEARCH_TERM(?![^/\*]*?\*/)
```

Explanation:

`(?<!//.*)` is a negative look-behind against single-line-comments (`//`)

`(?!(/\*).*)` invalidates your search term if it is preceded by `/*`

`(?![^/\*]*?\*/)` invalidates your search term if it is followed by `*/` (short of a `/*` between your search term and itself, because then your search term would be *outside* of /**/ and you want it to be matched again).

To use it in VS Code, just type `Ctrl` + `F` and tick the regex-icon in the search-field popping up (with *void* being your exemplary search term):

[image]

Comment: This answer covers all cases of commented code except

'/* This is an example of

multiple lines of comments

enclosed by special characters 

CAN WE EXCLUDE THIS LINE

as well? */'

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's an option in VS. You could try regular expressions, but those are limited by how creative you can be. It seems like it would be not entirely difficult to search for lines not beginning with // using a regex.

Comment: yeah, don't forget anything between /* .. */ too.