# Find rows that do not start with '//'

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to look for a regular expression which does not start with `//`
I tried Google but no luck.
I want to use this to find string in VS 2013 IDE.

String:

```
//debugger;
debugger; <--regex should match only this, rest has to ignore
//          debugger;
///   debugger;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exclude comments when searching in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314366/exclude-comments-when-searching-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Because they introduced big changes in VS2013 regular expression search, this is not a duplicate of [Exclude comments when searching in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314366/exclude-comments-when-searching-in-visual-studio). The solution looks completely different.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead assertion to exclude those lines

```
^(?!\s*//).*
```

`^` Matches the start of a row

`(?!\s*//)` is the negative lookahead, it is true, when the row is not starting with (optional) whitespace and "`//`".

`.*` matches the complete row

Answer (score 0):

Try the below RegEx

```
^([^?\/].*);(.*?)$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/vX5qJ3/3)

- First `^` marks the starting of a line and `$` marks the end of a line
- The text inside `[]` will be ignored by regex as it's mentioned along with `^` in the beginning
- `.*` is to match all text before `;`

Answer (score 0):

To match all lines but those starting with `//` use:

```
(?m)^[^/].*$
```

Comment: Its same as my answer but short!. BTW, the second `[^/]` is not needed. Its just that I am using capturing groups and you dont.