# regex to find a string, excluding comments

Tags: regex

I need a `regex` to search for the string `SQLHELPER` that ignores commented code (single line comment or multi line comments). I am searching in visual studio.

Comment: It is too hard to determine if a string is within multi line comments using regex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude comments when searching in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314366/exclude-comments-when-searching-in-visual-studio)

Comment: @JacobBoertjes : Yes , this might be a duplicate , but original post does not answer , how to exclude multi line comments , I had checked that post already.But I am looking for a single REGEX which can ignore both Single and multi line comments

Comment: After reading to comments on the other question, I would conclude that it is not possible to exclude multi line comments. Unfortunately the answers provided there are the best you are going to get.

Comment: Try [`(?<!^[\p{Zs}\t]*//.*)(?<!/\*(?:(?!\*/)[\s\S\r])*?)\bSQLHELPER\b`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5e%5b%5cp%7bZs%7d%5ct%5d*%2f%2f.*%29%28%3f%3c!%2f%5c*%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%5c*%2f%29%5b%5cs%5cS%5cr%5d%29*%3f%29%5cbSQLHELPER%5cb&i=SQLHELPER%0d%0a%2f%2f+SQLHELPER%0d%0aSQLHELPER%0d%0aSQLHELPER+%2f*+SQLHELPER++%2f*+SQLHELPER%0d%0ahere+SQLHELPER*%2f+++SQLHELPER%0d%0a%2f*+SQLHELPER+*%2f+SQLHELPER&o=m)

Comment: Will Visual Studio accept a lookbehind of non-fixed width though?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , THANKS Wiktor , it solved my problem , now it seaches in single and multi line comments also

Comment: So, shall I post an answer? You wanted to match outside of them, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes , post it as answer , it solves my problem , i tried searching for word SQLHELPER in all .CS file in VS , and it did not list commented out code ( single or multi ) , which was my requirment, thanks again

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<!^[\p{Zs}\t]*//.*)(?<!/\*(?:(?!\*/)[\s\S\r])*?)\bSQLHELPER\b
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5E%5B%5Cp%7BZs%7D%5Ct%5D*%2F%2F.*%29%28%3F%3C!%2F%5C*%28%3F%3A%28%3F!%5C*%2F%29%5B%5Cs%5CS%5Cr%5D%29*%3F%29%5CbSQLHELPER%5Cb&i=SQLHELPER%0D%0A%2F%2F%20SQLHELPER%0D%0ASQLHELPER%0D%0ASQLHELPER%20%2F*%20SQLHELPER%20%20%2F*%20SQLHELPER%0D%0Ahere%20SQLHELPER*%2F%20%20%20SQLHELPER%0D%0A%2F*%20SQLHELPER%20*%2F%20SQLHELPER&o=m).

**Details**

- `(?<!^[\p{Zs}\t]*//.*)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, the following pattern does not match:

  - `^` - start of line
  - `[\p{Zs}\t]*` - any 0+ horizontal whitespaces
  - `//` - a `//` substring
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `(?<!/\*(?:(?!\*/)[\s\S\r])*?)` -  - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if, immediately to the left of the current location, the following pattern does not match:

  - `/\*` -  a `/*` substring
  - `(?:(?!\*/)[\s\S\r])*?` - ([tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat)) any char (matched with `[\s\S\r]`), 0 or more repetitions but as few as possible (due to `*?`) that does not start a `*/` substring (due to the `(?!\*/)` negative lookahead)
- `\bSQLHELPER\b` - a whole word `SQLHelper` (`\b` are word boundaries).

[image]

Comment: If I use this in java I get :>  

java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
 
Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 48

Comment: @FergalFitz Of course, it is a JS ECMAScript 2018+ compliant regex. You can only use it in .NET, JS or Python PyPi regex.